# Why docker displays only 3 messages from the 3rd WARNING level in the log, and 5 messages from the 1st DEBUGGING level on the localhost? How resolve?

Tags: django, docker

I played a little in django docker with logging. And I don't understand why docker displays only 3 messages from the 3rd WARNING level in the log, and 5 messages from the 1st DEBUGGING level on the local host. Does anyone know what's going on?

[django code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYWcv.png)

[django logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f1Lb.png)

[Docker logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16DNC.png)

[dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrBAt.png)

[docker-compose.yml-1-part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlK15.png)

[docker-compose.yml-2-part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQPXg.png)

I tried add [logging property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6rV0.png) to change default docker logger level, but it doesn't work.

How set debug logging level in docker?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem: I forgot to import the logging part of my settings.

But I found settings for docker-compose.yml, that allow me to use print in docker.

service:

- stdin_open: true
- tty: true

But I think the logging is better!